# Why my form doesn't validate the fields?

Tags: javascript, validation, forms

I can't see a clear mistake in this code. Instead of validating my fields, it just tries to send my form and I don't know why.

This is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PAALA/

Other question, how to validate if select box was picked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, because of how JSFiddle works, defining a function with `function foo() {...}` is unreliable. Instead, use `foo = function() {...}` syntax.

Next, you have an error in your script when you try to access `document.forms["bug_form"]["Project"].value` - there is no text input with that name.

Finally, to prevent accidental submission, do this:

```
validateBugForm = function() {
    try {
        // ALL YOUR ORIGINAL CODE HERE
    }
    catch(e) {
        alert("An error occurred: "+e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will ensure that `false` is returned, even if your code errs.

Comment: Yeah, I should use try/catch statement more often :)

Answer (score 2):

The Javascript code is crashing out on the third line when you try to get the value for "Project".  Looks like you forgot to give that one a name.